# Use a list with Matplotlib bar_label() in order to label bar

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, matplotlib

Currently, I'm using the bar_label() new feature from Matplotlib v3.4.0.

My code is as follow and works perfectly :

```
ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0])
```

However, I would like to use different values as label. These values are available in a list.

I tried :

```
ax.bar_label(my_list)
```

But it doesn't work.

Is there any way to use bar_label() with a custom list ?

Comment: Did you check the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar_label.html) yet? Note the `labels` parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentionned in the comment by BigBen, `labels` parameter is the good thing to use.

Be careful to use also container (both are working together !)